# OpenWeatherMap API call 'icon' not working

Tags: ajax, api, icons

I'm trying to make ajax call to display current weather info however, only 'icon' is not displaying. All the other items are working just fine.

```
function APIcalls() {

    // URL to make API calls for current forecast
    let currentForeCastUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + 
                                city + "&appid=0fb779217270dc1943ca287687bf9395";
    
    $.ajax({
        url: currentForeCastUrl,
        method: "GET",
    }).then(function (response) {
        
        let temp = Math.round(((response.main.temp - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32));
        $("#icon").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + response.weather[0].icon + ".png");
        
    });

}
```

Comment: do you have `img` tag with `id="icon"` ? I tested your code its showing icon .

Comment: Ahh I thought I had <img> but it somehow got put in as <p> and that was why it didn't work! Thank you so much for correcting Swati!